# Rails 6 + Turbolinks doesn't load a 3rd party library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks

I am using a jQuery library for masking a phone number in inputs:

```
%script{src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'}
```

this is in the  tag.

Then, in my view, the code looks like this:

```
<form...
  <input id="phone_number" ... />
  ...
```

and after all the HTML, I have the following:
:javascript
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
console.log("Hello World!");
$("#phone_number").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999999"});
});

When I run this code, nothing happens, not even the `Hello World!` is printed out.

If I change the JS part to this:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  console.log("Hello World!");
  $("#phone_number").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999999"});
});
```

then the `Hello World!` is printed out and the input-masking plugin is working - great!

However, if I click some link within my application and then click back again to the page with the JS masking functionality, it breaks and returns this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).inputmask is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:13:32)
    ...
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: How are you loading the inputmask plugin - is it in your document's body by any chance?

Comment: The `inputmask` plugin is loaded from the `<HEAD>` tag; I also tried loading if from the `<BODY>` tag, specifically I placed it right before the closing `</BODY>` tag, but it didn't work either.

Comment: It should be in head.   does   $("#phone_number") exist right before the error?

Comment: @Joel_Blum the field is rendered in a Rails view - it is there..

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$(document).ready(function($)` to `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function($)`, so it will be:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function($){
  console.log("Hello World!");
  $("#phone_number").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999999"});
});
```

When using Turbolinks, instead of listen to the ready event, you need listen to the Turbolinks event fired for every page visit.

Ref: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events and https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/#observing-navigation-events

Comment: Hi @PedroSchmitt, thank you for your answer. If I use `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function($){` then the code inside it is never executed - `console.log("Hello World!");` is never printed out.

Comment: I think that '$' is misplaced... Could you try only `function()` instead of `function($)`?

Comment: Actually, I just tested on my Rails app, and it printed the 'hello world' using `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()` and `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function($)`. Is Turbolinks active?